# How can I install tamsyn fonts?

Tags: 15.04, fonts

I'm trying to install these fonts [Tamsyn fonts](http://www.fial.com/~scott/tamsyn-font/) on my Ubuntu 15.04.

As my user, created `~/.fonts` and copied `*.pcf` files over it.

Now running `fc-cache -f -v`

Fonts are still not visible from apps or font viewer? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88686/installed-fonts-not-showing-up-linux-mint-15-64bit) helped to solve my issue.

> the default config restricts the use of bitmap fonts, that's all.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf
$ sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-yes-bitmaps.conf
```

Nothing more is needed, the fonts should be available instantly.